# dynamic link attempts all yield statically linked binaries? Why?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm following this tutorial to the "T" [here](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) about creating a dynamically-linked shared library in Linux, and when I follow the instructions, gcc seems to statically link the library instead.

The tutorial proposes 3 files: `foo.c`, `foo.h`, and `main.c`.  Main includes `foo.h` and calls `foo()`, defined in `foo.c`.

I made one little change from the tutorial for debugging... my `foo` looks like this:

```
void foo(void) {
    int i = 54321;
    printf( "Shared lib: %d\n", i );
}
```

It tells me to compile using these 3 steps:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

When I run `./test`, it works, I can see the "hello 54321" from `foo()`. In fact, it works so well, it works if I delete `libfoo.so`. Seemed suspicious, so I did `objdump -S test` and found this little guy in the object file:

```
000000000000068a <foo>:
 68a: 55                    push   %rbp
 68b: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
 68e: 48 83 ec 10           sub    $0x10,%rsp
 692: c7 45 fc 31 d4 00 00  movl   $0xd431,-0x4(%rbp)
                                   ^^^  there's my constant, 54321, in hex.
                      should be in the "dynamic" object, not here, right?

 699: 8b 45 fc              mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 69c: 89 c6                 mov    %eax,%esi
 69e: 48 8d 3d af 00 00 00  lea    0xaf(%rip),%rdi        # 754 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 6a5: b8 00 00 00 00        mov    $0x0,%eax
 6aa: e8 b1 fe ff ff        callq  560 <printf@plt>
 6af: 90                    nop
 6b0: c9                    leaveq
 6b1: c3                    retq
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance...

P.S. Compiling on x86_64 Debian Stretch using `version gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You most likely have `libfoo.a` in the `/home/username/foo` directory.

Or you accidentally used `#include "foo.c"` when `#include "foo.h"` was intended.

You can try to figure out where the definition of `foo()` is coming into `test` with:

```
gcc -L/home/username/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo -Wl,-y,foo
```

which should show *reference* to `foo` coming from some `/tmp/xyz.o` and the *definition* coming from `<somewhere>`.

Comment: That was it!  I had `#include "foo.c"` in my main.c.  Good thinking!